# papervision 3d instacning

Tags: actionscript, papervision3d

- anyone actually successfully implement 3D object instancing with papervision 3d?
- and does it actually perform good enough to be used to instancing many copies of a single model (tress for example)?

so far I failed to correctly display the instances and I doubt the performance benefit of doing this as papervision 3d is using software render.

what I did basically is:

```
new_do3d.geometry = master_do3d.geometry;
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll get better performances with Away3D or Alternativa3D

Comment: thanks for pointing out. I also found:

[link](http://code.google.com/p/papervision3d/issues/detail?id=145)